# RuntimeError: Assertion `cur_target >= 0 && cur_target < n_classes' failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, pytorch, cross-entropy

I get:

> RuntimeError: Assertion `cur_target >= 0 && cur_target < n_classes'
>   failed.  at
>   /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1550796191843/work/aten/src/THNN/generic/ClassNLLCriterion.c:93

When running this code:

```
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    #Define the optimizer
    optimizer=optim.SGD(net.parameters(),lr=0.01,momentum=0.9)
    epochs=20
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        print ("epoch #", epoch)
        running_loss=0.0
        for i, data in enumerate(train_loader,0):
            inputs,labels=data
            inputs,labels= inputs.to(device),labels.to(device)
            optimizer.zero_grad()   
            #train
            output=net(inputs)
            loss=criterion(output,labels)

    print ("loss: ", loss.item())
    running_loss+=loss.item()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    print ('Finished Training')
```

Comment: I am facing same problem and still it's unsolved. I don't know how to solve that as well.

Comment: You are not indicating which library this module comes from. It's not a problem in Python or Anaconda, it's in the library which contains the code which emits the message (quick googling suggests Pytorch?)

Answer (score 1):

The exception says that one of your labels is out of bounds.
Maybe they start from 1 instead of 0? Try printing them out.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact error (yes, it's from Pytorch), I'll post my solution in case anyone else can benefit from it.

Mine was due to a mistake where I only had 2 outputs to the classifier, but the data had 3 labels.

Fixed by making sure the classifier gave 3 classes.